# JavaFX File Explorer Customized

Tags: file, javafx, jfilechooser, explorer

I'm developing a simple program where the user can choose a directory.

How can I build a file explorer customized (or not) but that look like this one? can you point me the direction? I tried JFileChooser, but it doesn't look like I can customize it.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sedj601/FileExplorer) is something I used to play with `JavaFX` ideas. Maybe you can get some ideas from here.

Comment: `JFileChooser` is swing. Are you asking about JavaFX or Swing?

Comment: I'm building this program using Intellij and I created a JavaFx project, I'm  using the Scene Builder too for the fxml file. My wish is build a explorer button that look's like that on the print.